# JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated in websphere 8.5

Tags: java, websphere, apache-axis, websphere-8, axiom

I am getting this error while deploying my application:

```
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: JVMVRFY013 class loading constraint violated; class=org/apache/axiom/om/impl/dom/DocumentImpl, method=getDomConfig()Lorg/w3c/dom/DOMConfiguration;, pc=0
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepareClassImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:291)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:531)
        at org.apache.axiom.core.NodeFactoryImpl.<init>(NodeFactoryImpl.java:87)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.DOOMNodeFactory.<init>(DOOMNodeFactory.java:32)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.DOOMNodeFactory.<clinit>(DOOMNodeFactory.java:25)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.OMDOMMetaFactory.<init>(OMDOMMetaFactory.java:40)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.OMDOMMetaFactory.<clinit>(OMDOMMetaFactory.java:38)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.dom.factory.OMDOMMetaFactoryLoader.load(OMDOMMetaFactoryLoader.java:28)
        at org.apache.axiom.locator.ImplementationFactory.parseImplementation(ImplementationFactory.java:141)
        at org.apache.axiom.locator.ImplementationFactory.parseDescriptor(ImplementationFactory.java:98)
        at org.apache.axiom.locator.DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.<init>(DefaultOMMetaFactoryLocator.java:87)
        at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1899)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.OMAbstractFactory.<clinit>(OMAbstractFactory.java:104)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisDescription.<init>(AxisDescription.java:72)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisConfiguration.<init>(AxisConfiguration.java:175)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.populateAxisConfiguration(DeploymentEngine.java:627)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.<init>(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:157)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:341)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.init(ServletWrapperImpl.java:168)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.loadOnStartupCheck(ServletWrapper.java:1375)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.doLoadOnStartupActions(WebApp.java:655)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinally(WebApp.java:621)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:449)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:170)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1219)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1514)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:704)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1096)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:786)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2238)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5488)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5614)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2243)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:502)
        ... 1 more
```

I have followed this link,but in this case the error is different.

```
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1011249
```

On removing,axiom-dom from my web app,its working fine.But I dont know that other class of axiom-dom might be used by my app.

Please help.

Also set parent last option.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using PARENT_LAST?  VerifyErrors of the type you're seeing are basically impossible without PARENT_LAST loading.

If you do need PARENT_LAST, you have to be VERY careful what you're putting in your app.  The messaging for VerifyErrors isn't terribly precise, but the most likely cause is that you have an XML API without the associated implementation (best guess is that DOMConfiguration class that's referenced in the method in the error message).

Comment: parent last is kept because I want my classes under my webapplication to be loaded first

Comment: That's certainly understandable... but you should be aware that using that comes with extra risks - PARENT_LAST is more susceptible to VerifyErrors and ClassCastExceptions, and there are some technologies (particularly core Java EE APIs like EJB or Servlet) that you simply can't package in a PARENT_LAST loader without breaking things.  Is there a specific library for which you believe you need your version rather than simply using the version that comes with the server?

Comment: The problem is that WebSphere's JAX-WS implementation is based on Axis2 and the Axis2 classes in WebSphere's runtime are visible to applications. Therefore the only way to use Axis2 packaged in an application deployed on WebSphere is to switch to PARENT_LAST.

Answer (score 0):

This likely means that there is a JAR in your application containing classes from the `org.w3c.dom` package. Try to identify that JAR and remove it.